# What is wrong with my Mac? Unknown df process

Tags: cpu, activity-monitor

I am using a 13-inch MBP 2019 running macOS 11.1.

My Mac has been running extremely slowly starting today. It seems as though a process called "df" is the problem, but I can't figure out what it is:
[image: Activity monitor showing df process]

What is it and why is it using all of my CPU? I was barely able to open the Activity Monitor because the computer was running so slowly and hot (spotlight didn't work, so I had to find it in Finder). The only thing that helps is restarting the computer, but it keeps happening.

I notice it happening because suddenly Internet pages won’t load in safari. Then a few minutes later the computer is running very hot and all apps stop responding. I can’t even shut down the computer without forcing it.

Comment: It seems odd that you have multiple instances of the command line tool that displays free disk space: https://ss64.com/osx/df.html  What if you reboot or reboot in Safe Mode?